# I have problems with Database inserting in eclispe

Tags: android, sql, database, sql-insert

I've created a simple app to get student's name and save it in database and if it is inserted , show a toast otherwise show a 'didn't work' toast. How can I find out my database is saved?

Here is my script codes:

**Student**

```
public class Student {

    public String Name;

}
```

**DatabaseManager**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseManager(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "myData", null, 1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String query = "CREATE TABLE tbl_student_Info ( " +
                " Name VARCHAR( 10 )," +
                ");";
        arg0.execSQL(query);

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String query = " DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_student_Info ";

        arg0.execSQL(query);

        onCreate(arg0);

    }


    public boolean addStudent(Student student)
    {
        boolean result;

        try
        {
            String query = "INSERT INTO tbl_student_Info (Name, Tel)" +
                    " VALUES ('" + student.Name + "')";
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL(query);
            db.close();
            result = true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        {
            result = false;

        }
        return result;
    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class TestDatabaseSimpleTestActivity extends Activity {

    EditText edittext1;

    Button   button1;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setTitle(" Registry page ");

        edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                String name = edittext1.getText().toString();

                Student student = new Student();

                student.Name = name;
                DatabaseManager db = new DatabaseManager(getApplicationContext());
                boolean result = db.addStudent(student);

                if (result == true)
                {
                    String s = "It works...";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    String s = "Did not works...";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name :" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Insert" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your logcat too! Switch to the warn tab for better understanding and  precise errors.

Comment: @SouravKanta I've edited. btw may you please tell me what's  wam tab and how can I switch to it?

Comment: that is not logcat, you posted from console.

Comment: @nobalG logcat is empty.

Comment: @SouravKanta that ^